# type 1 hypervisor boot sequence

Tags: boot, hypervisor, bare-metal

I have a very basic query with type 1 virtualization. I am really trying to understand the boot process.

A type 1 hypervisor basically runs at the bare metal level, communicating directly to hardware.

My question is that when a system boots and the bootstrap code loads, the next component that gets loaded is hypervisor or does initializing itself requires a management operating system initially ??

Can anyone kindly explain me the boot sequence with reference to a type 1 hypervisor ?

I thought it should be like the bootstrap code directly referencing the hypervisor component which in turn is responsible for loading the kernel of the other virtual VM instances.

Answer (score 1):

The boot sequence depends on the hypervisor.  Simplicity is often a goal with hypervisors.  If the system is statically configured (pre-configured tasks), then the entire process tables can be pre-coded in the image.  In this case, the initial boot is system initialization and a context switch to the highest priority task.  Ie, the image is like a *frozen* system image. Even with *dynamic* hypervisors, the *root* or *init* task can be coded like this; while other tasks are `spawned` as needed.

System initialization consists of,

- flushing caches, write-buffers, TLB's.
- setup up memory controllers.
- disable interrupts and setup stack.
- enabling the MMU.
- possibly locking kernel pages in cache.
- initializing the interrupt controller.
- possibly installing a hypervisor timer.

Really it mostly depends on the design of the *hypervisor*.  If it is non-preemtive and only priority based, then a timer might not be needed, for example.